# Ranking 5 Deck Poker Hands

Tags: probability, poker

I'm trying to create a poker game that uses 5 decks, and have run into a problem calculating how many possible combinations of suited 4 of a kinds there are.

Suited 5 of a kind seems easy enough.  To make a suited 5K of any given rank and suit, there are only 5 cards in the deck and you need all of them, so one combo per rank, per suit = 1 * 13 * 4 = 52 total suited 5Ks.

With suited 4K I tried the same approach, first calculating combinations of any given rank and suit (lets say Ace of Spades), then multiplying by 52.

My problem is with the first part.  There are two ways I've thought of it that both seem correct, but can't be as they give different results.

The deck has 5 Aces of Spades total, so there are 5 ways to make a suited 4K with 4 cards.  The problem comes with calculating how many 5 card combos that makes.  (Note there are 260 total cards in the deck to begin with).

**Option A:**  I have 5 combos of 4K and multiply by the remaining 255 cards in the deck, excluding the last Ace of Spades as it would make a suited 5 of a kind. 5 * 255 = 1275

**Option B:**  I have 5 combos of 4K and multiply by the remaining 256 cards in the deck, to get all combos of suited 4 of a kind, including the suited 5 of a kind for now.  5 * 256 = 1280.  Then remove the one combo of suited 5K to get 1279.

The difference is small enough to be negligible, but it's driving me insane not being able to understand this.

Comment: In **Option B**, you need to remove the 5K combo 5 times, not just once, because you had 5 combos of 4K and you can make a 5K out of any of them. Then you get the 1275 count for both options.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm pretty sure that you're right, but it's still giving me a headache to think about removing the 5K 5 times, as there's only one combination of suited 5k possible.

Comment: You have counted the 5K five times, once for each set of four that make the 4K.

Comment: Right.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Ok, so this opens up a new question.  My plan for calculating unsuited 5 of a kind, etc.  was to calculate all combinations of 5 of a kinds regardless of suit, then subtract the combinations of suited 5 of a kinds, and suited 4 of a kinds.  Will this give me correct results, or will the same situation occur?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "etc.". For unsuited $5$ of a kind, this problem will not occur, since you can readily count the number of combinations of five of a kind regardless of suit ($13\cdot\binom{20}5=201552$), and this correctly counts each such combination exactly once, so from that you can subtract the $52$ suited $5$ of a kind (and whatever else you might want to subtract). The problem might occur again if you want to calculate unsuited $4$ of a kind, depending on how you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has already been discussed in the comments, in option $B$ you're counting suited $5$ of a kind $5$ times and thus need to subtract it $5$ times.

Since your comments indicate that you intend to pursue further, more complicated calculations of this kind, you might want to learn about the [inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).